# Should tags be added based on answers?

Tags: discussion, tagging, retagging

> Should tags be added based on answers?

The specific case I have in mind is that every once in a while I answer questions using inclusion-exclusion but the question doesn't refer to inclusion-exclusion, because the asker didn't know about it or because it wasn't obvious that the solution might use it. Then I wonder whether people interested in inclusion-exclusion might nevertheless want to be able to find this question using that tag. So should tags be based only on the explicit content of the question or also on what the answers reveal to be implicit in the question?

Other tags that this might be particularly relevant for because they refer to solution methods that might not be obvious from the question: [induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/induction), [generating-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generating-functions), [contour-integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contour-integration).

Comment: This was previously discussed here: [Retagging after an answer is given](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612/retagging-after-an-answer-is-given). If I interpret the answers there correctly, then the consensus seems to be: Yes, but not in too excessive way. (I.e., not every minor thing which appears in an answers should automatically influence tags for the question.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thanks. My impression from the answers there is that if the answer(s) reveal that a particular solution method is well suited to solve the problem (because it's used in the only answer or the accepted answer or a particularly short/elegant/efficient/upvoted answer) then it would be appropriate to add its tag.

Comment: This is only marginally related, but perhaps it is also worth mentioning that a suggestion to have tags also on answers was declined: [Tags on answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/tags-on-answers).

Comment: My two cents, I think it really needs to be case-by-case. In your specific case, if inclusion-exclusion is the only way to answer the question, then yes, absolutely, the tag needs to be added.